# Validation summary going out of page

Tags: asp.net, validation, scroll

I have a panel displayed on a modal popup. The panel has some textboxes with validation controls. I am using validation summary at the bottom of the panel to display all validation errors. The problem is that the list of errors (validations) is going out of the panel (page) and the panel doesn't scroll... tried setting overflow to auto/scroll for the panel, didn't work... What is needed?

```
<div style="height:auto">
<asp:Panel ID="pnlMyAddressBook" runat="server" BackColor="White"  CssClass="roundcorner pnl">
    TEST<table style="width: 100%;">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="2">
                                                &nbsp;
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblMyAddressBookk" runat="server" CssClass="hlbl" Text="My Address Book"></asp:Label>
                                                &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                                            </td>
                                            <td colspan="2">
                                                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnClose" runat="server" Height="20px" src="Images1/close-icon.png"
                                                    Width="20px" ImageAlign="Right" OnClick="imgbtnClose_Click"  CausesValidation="false"/>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="width: 120px">
                                                &nbsp;
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblFisrtName" runat="server" Text="First Name"></asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="width: 200px">
                                                &nbsp;
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" CssClass="txtbx2"></asp:TextBox>
                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator11" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtFirstName" ErrorMessage="FirstName" Text="*" ValidationGroup="vg1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="width: 120px">
                                                &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblEmailAddress" runat="server" Text="Email Address"></asp:Label>
                                                &nbsp;
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="width: 100px">
                                                &nbsp;
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmailAddress" runat="server" CssClass="txtbx2"></asp:TextBox>
                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator10" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtEmailAddress" ErrorMessage="Email Address" Text="*" ValidationGroup="vg1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                &nbsp;
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblLastName" runat="server" Text="Last Name"></asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                &nbsp;
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server" CssClass="txtbx2"></asp:TextBox>
                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator9" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtLastName" ErrorMessage="LastName" Text="*" ValidationGroup="vg1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                &nbsp;
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblCity" runat="server" Text="City"></asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                &nbsp;
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server" CssClass="txtbx2"></asp:TextBox>
                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator8" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCity" ErrorMessage="City" Text="*" ValidationGroup="vg1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                &nbsp;
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblCountry" runat="server" Text="Country"></asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                &nbsp;
                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountry" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                                                    CssClass="ddl2" onselectedindexchanged="ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged" DataTextField="CountryName" DataValueField="ID">
                                                </asp:DropDownList><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator7" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlCountry" ErrorMessage="Country" Text="*" ValidationGroup="vg1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                &nbsp;
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblState" runat="server" Text="State"></asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                &nbsp;
                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlState" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                                                    onselectedindexchanged="ddlState_SelectedIndexChanged" DataTextField="StateName" DataValueField="ID" >
                                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlState" ErrorMessage="State" Text="*" ValidationGroup="vg1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                &nbsp;
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblAddress" runat="server" Text="Address"></asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                &nbsp;
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddressLine1" runat="server" CssClass="txtbx2"></asp:TextBox>
                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAddressLine1" ErrorMessage="Address Line 1" Text="*" ValidationGroup="vg1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                &nbsp;
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblPostalCode" runat="server" Text="Postal Code"></asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                &nbsp;
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPostalCode" runat="server" CssClass="txtbx2"></asp:TextBox>
                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPostalCode" ErrorMessage="Postal Code" Text="*" ValidationGroup="vg1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                &nbsp;
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                &nbsp;
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddressLine2" runat="server" CssClass="txtbx2"></asp:TextBox>
                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator12" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAddressLine2" ErrorMessage="Address Line2" Text="*" ValidationGroup="vg1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                &nbsp;
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblMobile" runat="server" Text="Mobile"></asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                &nbsp;
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtMobile" runat="server" CssClass="txtbx2"></asp:TextBox>
                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtMobile" ErrorMessage="Mobile" Text="*" ValidationGroup="vg1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                &nbsp;
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                &nbsp;
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddressLine3" runat="server" CssClass="txtbx2"></asp:TextBox>
                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator13" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAddressLine3" ErrorMessage="Address Line 3" Text="*" ValidationGroup="vg1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                &nbsp;
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                &nbsp;
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                &nbsp;
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblTelephone" runat="server" Text="Telephone"></asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                &nbsp;
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtTelephone" runat="server" CssClass="txtbx2"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                &nbsp;
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                &nbsp;
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="2">
                                                &nbsp;
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblDefaultShippingAddress" runat="server" Text="Default Shipping Address"></asp:Label>
                                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkDefaultShippingAddress" runat="server" />
                                                &nbsp;
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                &nbsp;
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                &nbsp;
                                                <asp:Button ID="btnSaveAddress" runat="server" CssClass="btn" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSaveAddress_Click" ValidationGroup="vg1" CausesValidation="true" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
    <asp:Button ID="btnOk" runat="server" Text="Ok" />
       <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" HeaderText="You must enter a value in the following fields:"
 DisplayMode="BulletList"
 EnableClientScript="true" runat="server" ValidationGroup="vg1"/>
</asp:Panel> </div>
```

CSS:

```
 .pnl
{
overflow:auto;
height:auto;
}
```

Comment: What is needed? An example of your code so we can see what is wrong. Please post your HTML/CSS/ASP.net markup.

Comment: you need to set the height on the .pnl if you want the content to scroll.

Comment: I already did that, din't I? Plus, that makes no difference...tried...

Comment: I think it's the height:auto;